# include statement casuing expected function body error

Tags: c++, xcode

Im coding C++ in xcode and the following code is causing an "expected function body after after function delarator" error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Implementation.hpp"
using namespace std;
```

the error is popping up after implementation.hpp

here is my implementation.hpp file:

```
    #ifndef Implementation_hpp
#define Implementation_hpp

using namespace std;



#include <stdio.h>

int* getLottoPicks(int picks[]);
int genWinNums();
bool noDuplicates(int picks[], int input)

#endif /* Implementation_hpp */
```

if anyone could find the issue i would greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Missing semicolon after `noDuplicates` declaration.

Comment: Since you don't have a semicolon there, it looks like the beginning of a function definition, not a declaration. That's why it complains that the body is missing.

Comment: Thank you so much, very stupid error haha.

Answer (score 0):

That compile error comes from here:

```
bool noDuplicates(int picks[], int input) // ';' or body expected
```

Without `;`, your compiler expects a function body `{ /* code */ }` to come, which you do not provide.

You have two options, one of which is to provide a proper function body as follows:

```
bool noDuplicates(int picks[], int input)
{
    // Code
}
```

the other of which is to *declare* as follows:

```
bool noDuplicates(int picks[], int input); // note that ';' is used.
```